# Package dependency between application and package

Tags: flutter-dependencies, pubspec

Let's say that I created a local package that has this pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: x1.y1.z1. /// Just an example of a package
```

This is just to simulate working with a package. Imagine that this package can be a developer package that I did not develop.

Let's also assume that I have a simple application with the following pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: x2.y2.z2
  package_name:
    path: PATH_TO_LOCAL_PACKAGE
```

I am trying to resolve the following issues:

1. If the package has a version of webview_flutter that is higher than that of the application
2. If the package has a version of webview_flutter that is lower than that of the application

The error I get is:

> Because every version of package_name from path depends on webview_flutter 2.4.0 and resolving_depedencies depends on webview_flutter 2.3.0, package_name from path is forbidden.
> So, because resolving_depedencies depends on package_name from path, version solving failed.
> pub get failed

In both of these scenarios, if x1 and x2 are equal (meaning the same major version), this can be solved easily with the **caret** (^) syntax (taken from [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies)).

My problem is when the major versions (x1, x2) are different.

For example,

```
x1.y1.z1 = 3.0.0
x2.y2.z2 = 2.3.0
```

I am aware of the [dependency overrides](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) option, but it is not something I want to do.

Obviously, in the scenario where the package has a higher version than the application, I can update the application, but in the scenario where the package has a higher version, I won't be able to do that.

Is there any way to solve this scenario without dependency overrides?

Comment: If I understood correctly, your problem is your app has, let's say `webview_flutter: ^4.0.0`, and the other package you can't control depends on something like `webview_flutter: ^3.0.0`, is that correct?

Comment: @maxime_rougieux - I don't have a problem per se. I am asking about a scenario where an application and a package have different major versions of a library and how one can resolve this. The caret symbol is not that relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

First, I advise you to read this [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning) which is awesome to understand how pub resolves your dependencies.

From that documentation, we learn that:

- pub resolves each dependency to a **unique version.**
- As stated [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning#you-can-have-disjoint-constraints), you can have disjoint constraints which makes the resolving impossible.

In your case, if the package has a lower version of `webview_flutter` than you, then you are bound to use its version at most, or to use `dependency_overrides` (which is highly dangerous because then it might break the package which depends on a lower version).

Your next step should be to ask the package maintainer to update its dependency, and to downgrade your version of the dependency in the meantime.